# Не работает .hasClass

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap

Мой скрипт:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  if ( $("#menu-xs" ).hasClass('in') ) {
    $( ".main-bg" ).css("height","500px");
  }
});
```

Айди `#menu-xs` - это меню, которое появляется с помощью бутстраповского `collapse`. Когда оно появляется - ему присваивается класс `.in`. Данный скрипт почему-то не хочет видеть этого. Отдельно строка с действием после ифа выполняется. Стоит задача выполнять эту строку при появлении `#menu-xs`. Подскажите, будьте добры, в чем может быть проблема. Благодарю.

Comment: например проверка осуществляется _до_ того, как данному элементу добавлен указанный класс

Comment: Когда оно появляется - ему присваивается клас .in - когда оно появляется это когда? Может класс ему присваеватся после проверки?) приведите код где вы ему присваиваете это значение. И еще у вас опечатка в коде. Нету скобки закрывающей - `}`

Comment: @Grundy, а как сделать так что бы это проверка выполнялась постоянно?

Comment: Скобку поправил, в коде она была

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ваш скрипт выполняется только один раз - при загрузке страницы. Задача, как я понял, стоит другая - запускать скрипт при появлении `collapse`. Для этого вам нужно привязаться к событию `collapse` у `bootstrap`. [Вот список этих событий](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-events). Вам, вероятно, нужно `shown.bs.collapse`. Код будет таким:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#menu-xs').on('shown.bs.collapse', function(){
    $( '.main-bg' ).css('height', '500px');
  })
});
```

Comment: Благодарю за ответ. Практически так, пришлось только немного поправить, вместо `show.bs.collapse` поставил `shown.bs.collapse`. В итоге получился следующий скрипт:   `$(document).ready(function(){  
  $('#menu-xs').on('shown.bs.collapse', function(){  
    $( '.main-bg' ).css('height', '500px');  
  })  
});`

Comment: Спасибо, скорректировал ответ.